# How to add 2 hours in doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

With the following code,

```
protected $token;
 /** @Column(name="assigneddate", type="datetime", columnDefinition="datetime") */
private $assigneddate;


/** @Column(name="expirydate", type="datetime", columnDefinition="datetime") */
private $expirydate;

/** @PreUpdate */
public function updated()
{
    //$this->assigneddate = new \DateTime("now");
}
public function __construct()
{

    $this->expirydate = $this->expirydate = new \DateTime("now");
    $this->assigneddate = $this->assigneddate = new \DateTime("now");
```

}

How do I add 2 hours to this?

Comment: Note, you must be very careful with DateTime instances in Doctrine.  Because DateTime is not immutable in PHP, you can modify the value using methods such as add().  However Doctrine WILL NOT ALWAYS PERSIST CHANGED VALUES BACK TO THE DATABASE unless you create a new instance of DateTime to hold the modified value.  See this page for further discussion on the topic http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

Answer (score 7):

This is more of a PHP question. To add time to a [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) PHP object, you use the [add method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php), which accepts a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object. In your case, if you want to add 2 hours to the expiry date:

```
// Create DateTime object with current time/date
$this->expirydate = new \DateTime("now");
// Add two hours
$this->expirydate->add(new \DateInterval("PT2H"));
```

Where "PT2H" means a "period time of 2 hours", as specified [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php).

Comment: i get an error: DateInterval::__construct() [<a href='dateinterval.--construct'>dateinterval.--construct</a>]: Unknown or bad format (P2H)

Answer (score 2):

By default doctrine only allowing intervals `DAY`, `MONTH` and `YEAR` I guess. When trying to date add example 8 HOUR, it returns an error.

**But you can do this trick:**

```
Let 8 be the number of hours
Let 24 be the number of hours a day.

8/24 = decimal presentation of the hour.

$nHour = 8/24; //result will be: 0.3333333
```

**then use it in doctrine as:**

```
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), $nHour, 'DAY') as dateaddhour
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It's PT2H.

```
$this->expirydate = new \DateTime("now");
// Add two hours
$this->expirydate->add(new \DateInterval("PT2H"));
```

Comment: For Doctrine, you need to clone the DateTime object in order to allow Doctrine to detect the reference change and to persist it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a couple of other alternatives to the already given answers from the entity side.

You don't need to add or modify the date, you can create a new DateTime object with Relative Formats http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

For example: `last friday of june 2011` (2011-06-24)

It wasn't really clear on the behavior the OP was after or having issues with, so providing a few methods.

If wanting to add 2 hours when the object is created

```
/**
 * "now" is implicit
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->assigneddate = new \DateTime;
    $this->expirydate = new \DateTime('+2 hour');
}
```

Or when an update occurs

```
  /**
  * @PreUpdate
  */
  public function updated()
  {
      $this->assigneddate = new \DateTime;
      $this->expirydate = new \DateTime('+2 hour');
  }
```

Another alternative to ensure the existing value is updated in Doctrine when  modified/add/sub is called on it. With `PHP 5.5` you can now use `DateTimeImmutable` So if you are wanting to increment/modify the `expirydate` time by 2 hours.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->expirydate = new \DateTimeImmutable;
    $this->assigneddate = new \DateTimeImmutable;
}

/**
 * @PreUpdate
 */
public function updated()
{
    $this->assigneddate = new \DateTimeImmutable;
    $this->expirydate = $this->expirydate->modify('+2 hour');
}
```

This will cause the `expirydate` to add 2 hours to the existing expirydate,  since `DateTimeImmutable` will always return a new object, which doctrine will then process.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php