# Doctrine 2 DATE_ADD mysql function with computed interval value

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, sql-date-functions

I have a query that gives me a unix timestamp calculated selecting the datetime value of a table field and then adding another value of the table. The query is something like the following:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(mydatetimefield, INTERVAL m.myfield1 + m.myfield2 MINUTE)) FROM mytable AS m
```

this query executes correctly from phpMyAdmin but when I try to use it with the createQueryBuilder method of Doctrine 2 I get an error at "myfield". It seems that it doesn't support a computed value after the INTERVAL keyword

```
Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_COMMA, got 'm'
```

how can I then get the same query result by using doctrine? I use the querybuilder because I have some named parameters

Comment: You should provide the code used with the `createQueryBuilder` also.

Comment: did you simplify the query in your example as well?

Comment: How to use DATE_ADD OR DATE_SUB having the interval as number of hours.
**Refer to this answer:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/22223127/879708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Doctrine does not support all the functions of a specific vendor, such as the `DATE_ADD`.  However, you can use custom defined functions.  That link has an example specifically for date add.

[Extending DQL in Doctrine 2: User-Defined Functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/29/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html)

The other option, depending on the complexity of the query, is just to handle this in the application code.  if your `mydatetimefield` is actually a datetime, Doctrine will convert that to a php `DateTime` in the returned object.

```
$myDateTimeField = $object->getMyDateTimeField();
$myDateTimeField->add(new DateInterval( $object->getMyField1() + $object->getMyField2() . 'M'));
```

Lastly, you could always use `dbal` as well.

Comment: I get an error when I try to use that DateAdd function: "It is not allowed to overwrite internal function 'date_add' in the DQL parser through user-defined functions". Why?

Comment: Looks like they added `DATE_ADD` - though, looking at the docs, Doctrine's implementation only supports adding `day` and `month` intervals - [DQL Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) - if you wanted to create your own which allowed minutes, you would need to use a different name for the function.

Comment: I find really bad that we can't override default functions, however I solved by using a raw sql query instead of DQL

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cause, but since it is complaining about a missing comma where you have the `m` alias I suspect that it is not able to parse properly the user defined functions.

Have you defined the `DATE_ADD` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` as [DQL User Defined Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#dql-user-defined-functions)? See [Date Add](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#date-add) example for more details.

Comment: removing the UNIX_TIMESTAMP custom function doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @Stefano And you have `DATE_ADD` defined as a custom function?

Comment: no, I don't. I was trying to use the DATE_ADD function as in MySQL but then I saw Doctrine 2 doesn't support the INTERVAL and also doesn't have full support for all types (hours, minutes, etc.). I will use the function reported by kmfk

Comment: @Stefano It's your choice, but you can also use DATE_ADD too, see the example link that I have provided in my answer.

Comment: the code of the DateAdd function you posted is the same that I found on github via kmfk. The author of the function and of the article is the same