Doctrine querybuilder DATE_FORMAT / DATE_ADD in addSelect not working
I'm having some problems with DATE_FORMAT / DATE_ADD inside a createQueryBuilder
My code:
$em = $this->getEntityManager()->
createQueryBuilder()->
select('jo')->
addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(jo.createdAt, INTERVAL 14 DAY), "%Y-%m-%d") as deleteDate')->
from(JobOfferEntity::class, 'jo')->
where('jo.isDeleted = :isDeleted')->
setParameter('isDeleted', 0);

I'm getting floow error:
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 55: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_COMMA, got '14'

Can anybody help me?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/13503023/1427878

The bit that's easy to miss is that query builder expects DQL rather than SQL, so you can't always use the same syntax and expressions than you'd use in a regular database query.
